# android app - Java crush when i try to use vibrate

Tags: java, android

I look at previous questions about this issue but I couldn't find an answer.
I want when the text is empty then the device will vibrate but when I try to run my app the application crush

I will be happy to get help

I include this line in the XML file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.noambs;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Vibrator;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String VIBRATE = "android.permission.VIBRATE";
    EditText firstName;
    EditText lastName;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.print);
    }

    public void printName(View view) {
        String firstNameS = firstName.getText().toString();
        String lastNameS = lastName.getText().toString();

        if (checkValidName(firstNameS) && checkValidName(lastNameS))
            textView.setText(firstNameS + " " + lastNameS);
        else {
            vibrate(500);
        }

    }
    public void vibrate(int duration)
    {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(duration, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            vibrator.vibrate(duration);
        }
    }
    private boolean checkValidName(String name) {
        return !name.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

Comment: add the logcat error.

Comment: Hey i manage to find my mistake ( i add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> in wrong place )

but I don't see any vibrate when I run the app how can I know it's works?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using an emulator because of your comment under your answer and since you got the crash fixed I'll just answer your comment.

I copied your code and successfully entered your vibration method. I was able to confirm that the emulator is vibrating by using a `log` message as displayed below:

```
public void vibrate(int duration)
{
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.i("VIBRATING", "YES");
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(duration, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
    } else {
        Log.i("VIBRATING", "YES");
        vibrator.vibrate(duration);
    }
}
```

Then checking the log....

[image: VIBRATING]

The emulator was never going to physically/virtually vibrate.